# My intel hd 3000 + core i3 processor is performing really bad

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, performance

I've used Ubuntu before on my old laptop, sporitng an AMD V-series CPU and a mobile radeon 4250, both really bad compared to my laptop now. However, with ubuntu on both computers, my old laptop definetely knocks my intel i3 laptop out of the park. The graphics are slow and sluggish, and my mouse pointer feels a bit lagged. Can anyone help me???

Comment: How about your **RAM** compared to the old system? I also had may problems when I had low RAM(2GB) in a new laptop I bought. Later upgraded the ram and the performance got much better.